# Does OpenCV's undistortPoints also rectify them?

Tags: calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to determine the distance between two object by using two cameras (OCV 2.3.1, MSVC++, Win7) but can't calculate the object's objectPoints.  I think this is because the image points aren't being rectified before their disparity is calculated.

I. WHAT I DO FIRST
Step 1. Calibrate each camera by itself

```
int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

Mat cameraMatrix = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
Mat distCoeffs;

vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;

cameraMatrix.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1;
cameraMatrix.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1;

calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), 
                    cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
```

Step 2. Calibrate the cameras to together.
int numCornersHor = 4;
int numCornersVer = 3;
const float squareSize = 1.75;

```
Size imageSize = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);
   int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;

for(int i = 0; i < pairs; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < imageSize.height; j++ )
    {
        for( int k = 0; k < imageSize.width; k++ )
        {
            objectPoints[i].push_back(Point3f(j*squareSize, k*squareSize, 0));
        }
    }
}

Mat R, T, E, F;

rms = stereoCalibrate(  
    objectPoints, 
    imagePoints[0],     imagePoints[1],
    cameraMatrix[0],    distCoeffs[0],
    cameraMatrix[1],    distCoeffs[1],
    imageSize, 
    R,  T,  E,  F,
    TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
    CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
    CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
            CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH +
    CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL +
    CV_CALIB_FIX_K3 +   CV_CALIB_FIX_K4 +   CV_CALIB_FIX_K5
    );
```

Step 3. Create the rectification data
stereoRectify(
cameraMatrix[0],    cameraMatrix[1],
distCoeffs[0],      distCoeffs[1],
imageSize,
R,  T,
RC1, RC2,  //RC1: Rotation matrix Camera 1
PC1, PC2,
Q,
CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY,
1,
imageSize);

II. WHAT I BELIEVE
Goal:
I'm trying undistort and rectify the image points of one object in the image from camera 1 and the image from camera 2 (I do this process twice: once while the clay pigeon's on the launcher and once one frame before the clay pigeon disintegrates)

Method:
I believe that I don't need to use initUndistortRectifyMap then Remap but can instead just use undistortPoints.  I think undistortPoints undistorts the points of interest and rectifies them.

III. WHAT I DO SECOND
You can ignore this if my beliefs aren't correct.

```
undistortPoints(launcherC1, launcherC1Undistorted, cameraMatrixC1, distCoeffsC1, R1, P1);   
undistortPoints(launcherC2, launcherC2Undistorted, cameraMatrixC2, distCoeffsC2, R2, P2);   

undistortPoints(clayPigeonC1, clayPigeonC1Undistorted, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1); 
undistortPoints(clayPigeonC2, clayPigeonC2Undistorted, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2);
```

The input and output arrays for undistortPoints (launcherC1, launcherC1Undistorted, ... clayPigeonC2, clayPigeonC2Undistorted) are vectors of Point2f objects.

IV. DISCREPANCY BETWEEN BELIEF AND REALITY
After all undistortPoints functions are run,

1. launcherC1Undisorted.y does not equal launcherC2Undistorted.y
2. clayPigeonC1Undistorted.y does not equal clayPigeonC2Undistorted.y.
   They are up to 30% different.

V. QUESTIONS
Q1: In addition to undistorting them does undistortPoints also rectify points?
Q1.1_yes. Are the values of y supposed to be equal after rectification?
Q1.1.1_yes   Can you tell from the code I've included what I'm doing wrong so that they don't?
Q1_no  If undistortPoints doesn't rectify the points then how do I rectify them?

Thank you for any assistance.
Charles++

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33281/does-opencv%27s-undistortpoints-also-rectify-them?/) by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Charles,

Your question doesn't have much to do with ROS, maybe you should ask it on an OpenCV forum, but as long as you made the effort to post it so nicely let my try to answer it.

As far as I know undistortPoints do not rectify the points. The correct approach would be to call initUndistortRectifyMap and then use Remap.

If instead of remapping the whole image what you need is to undistort and rectify only some image points, then what you can do is use manually the maps (mapx and mapy) generated by initUndistortRectifyMap. Something like this (assuming that point1 is a point on the original image):

```
undistortedRectifiedPoint.x = mapx[point1.x, point1.y]
undistortedRectifiedPoint.y = mapy[point1.x, point1.y]
```

I hope this helps.

Best regards,
Martin.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-15**:
I can't read mapx & mapy.  I try Mat mapxC1;        mapxC1.create(sizeImage,1);
initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, camMat1UndistRect, sizeImage,       0,  /* ???*/  mapxC1, mapyC1);

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-15**:
vector point1Cam1UndistortedRectified;
point1Cam1UndistortedRectified.at(0).x = mapxC1[PointC1x, PointC1y];
point1Cam1UndistortedRectified.at(0).y = mapxC1[PointC1x, PointC1y];
but MSVC++ says not operator "[]" matches these operands right after mapxC1 in the last two lines.  Know why?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-05-15**:
Hi CharlesM,
Actually the syntax "mapxC1[PointC1x, PointC1y]" is not correct, sorry I misled you with my pseudo-code. How about mapxC1.at(PointC1x,PointC1y)?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-05-15**:
You can find more info on how to access OpenCV matrices efficiently here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-16**:
Hi Martin, Thank you so much for your help! I know I'll reach the answer being assisted by an OCV expert.  You told me how to put exactly the data I want into maps but now I'm frustrated since I still can't get that data. I tried your suggestion and link.  Results:

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-16**:
1.) MSVC++ says about mapxC1.at(PointC1x,PointC1y) that no overloaded functn matches argumnt list and that there are too many args in functn call.
2.) I don't know OCV or C++ well enough to make enough sense of the link you sent to get at a map's data

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-16**:
What I've done: PointC1x & PointC1y are floats that are the x & y of Keypoint objects in an image that's been cvtColor( ... CV_RGB2GRAY)

Q.) Am I even creating the Mat for the map correctly  mapxC1.create(sizeImage,1);   ?   Charles Mennell

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-05-16**:
The problem is that the parameters PointC1x and PointC1y should be integers (remember, after all, you are accessing data stored in the computer's memory which can only be indexed using integer numbers). Try: mapxC1.at(static_cast(PointC1x), static_cast(PointC1y))

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-05-16**:
The correct way to create mapxC1 would be: mapxC1.create(sizeImage, CV_16UC1). You want it to be a single channel matrix of 16 bit unsigned integers

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-19**:
Thank you squared, Martin,
The values held at the pixel represented by and x and a y pixel can be floats, right, just not the pixel (since a pixel is just 1 pixel at a location defined by two integers: row and column number)?

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-19**:
Does a single channel matrix mean that for each row & column matrix location there is one object, in this case a16 bit unsigned integer?

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-19**:
Tried mapxC1.at(s. After 1st . MSVC says "no OL func matches arg list" & it undrlines 2nd arg & says too many arguments. Why does VC say this when as I'm typing the args it says arg options are  "const_Tp & at<_Tp> (cv::Point pt) const or in the () could be things like int i0, i1 or just i0=0? ...

**Comment by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on 2012-05-19**:
... I don't understand the _Tp, &, or <> but I do understand a Point and integer and MSVC has complained when I've sent it just a Point, and when it's sent two ints or just one